# Java Swing popup visibility

Tags: java, swing, popup

Why a popup created like this is shown in front of all windows applications with JRE 1.6.0_18 but it doesn't using 1.6.0_03 ?

```
PopupFactory popupFactory = new PopupFactory();
    Popup popup= popupFactory.getPopup(null,new JPanel(),200,200);
    popup.show();
```

Comment: Note: The current secure version of the JRE is 6u20.

Comment: (Also, what does it mean to open a popup on a panel that is not attached to a visible window.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like "something" has changed between those JRE versions. They have either fixed a bug or introduced a new one. I don't think there's more magic than that.

If you are very interested in knowing what exactly has changed, you can check out this link: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/ReleaseNotes.html